# Dereferencing an array value via pointer to the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm probably missing something obvious, but my C is pretty rusty and I'm not having any luck making sense of this.  I have a loop where I want to iterate over an array of `uint64_t` values coming from libdvdnav and then format the values and insert them into a string.

The header for libdvdnav defines the function I'm calling thusly:

```
uint32_t dvdnav_describe_title_chapters(dvdnav_t *self, int32_t title, uint64_t **times, uint64_t *duration);
```

Here's how I'm defining the variables used and executing the call (`dvdnav` and `args[0]` are defined and initialized elsewhere):

```
uint64_t *times;
uint64_t duration;
uint32_t times_array_len;

times_array_len = dvdnav_describe_title_chapters(dvdnav, atoi(args[0]), &times, &duration);
```

The code below seems to work, and compiles & runs w/o error, but of course only the first value in the array is inserted:

```
int i = 0;
uint64_t a_time = times[0];

while(i < times_array_len){

    char time_json[100];
    sprintf(time_json, "{\"chapter\":\"%d\",\"time\":\"%u\"},", i, a_time);
    strcat(payload, time_json);
    i++;
}
```

If I modify this to select each value in the array it still compiles clean, but throws a segfault at runtime:

```
int i = 0;

while(i < times_array_len){

    char time_json[100];
    sprintf(time_json, "{\"chapter\":\"%d\",\"time\":\"%u\"},", i, times[i]);
    strcat(payload, time_json);
    i++;
}
```

I thought maybe there was something in one of the array elements that was a problem (a too-large value, unexpected, NULL, etc.) but even if I replace the variable `i` with a known-reasonable element (say, `0`) it still segfaults.

I'm sure there's countless other improvements to be made here (safer allocations, overflow protection, etc.) but the part I'm struggling to decipher is getting those values out of the array an into my formatted string.

Comment: "throws a segfault at runtime" -- where?  Fire up a debugger.

Comment: That `strcat()` call looks scary ...

Comment: There are 2 possible problems. First you have some mistakes in calculating `times_array_len`, and `times` is smaller then it is. Second your payload too short for save all this data.

Comment: Looks like the segfault is on the strcat() line @BrianCain

Comment: Given the above I increased the size of the `payload` buffer and got it to work; seems like I had done that before but perhaps not enough.  I do want to make sure that's not just masking other problems though so I'm going to poke at it a bit before considering it fixed :)

Comment: I'd recommend making sure your `sprintf()` does not invoke undefined behaviour: having a `%u` specifier and passing in a `uint64_t` may not be a good idea (depending on the size of your `int`?).

Comment: this line: atoi(args[0]) is sourcing the name of the currently executing file, and (probably) passing 0 to the called function.  Most likely, that arg should be: atoi(args[1])   and all the code seems to make the assumption the 'title' is a number rather than a text string.

Comment: this line: uint64_t *times; is only defining a pointer, not an array. yet the code is expecting an array when it says 'times[x]'  does this mean the call sets the pointer to an array created within the call?

Comment: @user3629249 here args[] is actually arguments coming in from a command stream (not the command line) so 0 is the correct index, but now that you mention it a better name might be less confusing for future users of the code (myself included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is `payload` defined? If it is too short to contain the strings then you will get a crash.
You can tackle this in several ways:

1) Since you now the number of json entries will be `times_array_len` you can allocate the string on heap using `malloc` with the size 100 * `times_array_len` - you will never exceed that (again, not sure if it is smart using a fixed length for the json buffer), then strcat should be safe. You can even do direct `sprintf` calls into the `payload` buffer dirrectly since you will now how far the offset is by keeping track of the return value of `sprintf`. Something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    __int64 pTimes[] = { 1, 2, 3 ,4};
    size_t nTimeCount = sizeof(pTimes) / sizeof(pTimes[0]);
    size_t nPayloadOffset = 0;
    char* pPayload = (char*)malloc(100 * nTimeCount);
    if (pPayload)
    {
        for (size_t nTimeIndex = 0; nTimeIndex < nTimeCount; ++nTimeIndex)
        {
            nPayloadOffset += sprintf(&pPayload[nPayloadOffset], "{\"chapter\":\"%d\",\"time\":\"%u\"},", nTimeIndex, pTimes[nTimeIndex]);
        }
        printf("%s\n", pPayload);
        free(pPayload);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

2) To avoid running over the 100 character length on a single entry you could be wise and allocate the `pPlayoad` with an initial size, then calculate the size of each entry and reallocate the `pPayload` if it becomes too short

3) Use C++ and `std::stringstream` if C++ is an option:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    __int64 pTimes[] = { 1, 2, 3 ,4};
    size_t nTimeCount = sizeof(pTimes) / sizeof(pTimes[0]);
    size_t nPayloadOffset = 0;
    std::stringstream JsonStream;
    for (size_t nTimeIndex = 0; nTimeIndex < nTimeCount; ++nTimeIndex)
    {
        JsonStream << "{\"chapter\":\"" << nTimeIndex << "\",\"time\":\"" << pTimes[nTimeIndex] << "\"},";
    }
    std::cout << JsonStream.str() << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```